# How to solve "undefined reference error"?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, linker, extern, modifier

I've started learning C language. I tried using extern variable modifier but it is showing undefined reference error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6JWu.png)

I have declared int a in xyz.c file same as shown in video lecture.

Comment: First of all welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And don't post images of your code or error, copy-paste as *text*.

Comment: As for your problem, when you add the `extern` keyword to a variable declaration, it's a *declaration*, telling the compiler that the variable exists somewhere, but not here. What you need is a *definition*, which you get by deleting the `extern` keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have just started learning C I advise avoiding more advanced language features before you become a bit more proficient.

1. Remove `extern`. Do not use it before you start writing multi source file programs and understand the linkage concept.
2. `main` declaration is wrong. It should be `int main(void)` if main does not take any parameters.